# Where should create nlog static file?

Tags: sql-server, nlog, visual-studio-2013

I am new Nlog and I have configured Nlog in my web.config. I am configuring the nlog to sql server database.
Now my confusion is how should i invoke the nlog whenever my application throw an error?
I read as we should create a static log file then from that we should call methods to wherever we need the logs. But please someone help me on this. Iam quite confused on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research i have applied the NLog in my project. The following link helped me to resolve it.
[NLog in MVC](http://dotnetdarren.wordpress.com/2010/07/28/logging-in-mvc-part-3-%E2%80%93-nlog/)
Its pretty easy :)